# How to access CSS Grid properties w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a dashboard with drag and drop. The main purpose of that dashboard is that the user can customize the cards and their position on the grid. So, for that funcionality I wanna get the columns and row to dinamically fill the empty cells with placeholders for the drag and drop. There's a way to get the CSS Grid properties via Javascript?

Comment: This is too broad a question. You want to first figure out what CSS styles (or HTML element positions) change the grid in the way you desire, for a given drag/drop event. Then program accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

this is how to access the css grid property

```js
yourElement.style.grid="250px / auto auto auto"
```

check this link, it contains the full explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_grid.asp